# Jersey gives "null" element for empty list

Tags: java, jersey

I have an endpoint using Jersey which takes an object. The object has a list as one of the members. However, when I send an empty array, it is giving me an empty element in the list. By 'empty element', I mean that there's an object there and all the fields are null.

```
@XMLRootElement
public class myContainer {
  public List<myObject> list;
  // etc
}

@XMLRootElement
public class myObject {
  public String data1;
  public String data2;
  // etc
}

// I hit the following with "{\"list\":[]}"    

@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response post(final myContainer x) {
  for (myObject obj : x.list) {
    // why do I hit this?
    // debugging, I actually have an object here with all null fields
    obj.data1 == null; // true
    obj.data2 == null; // true
  }
}
```

Anyone know why Jersey would do this?

I have WRITE_NULL_PROPERTIES set to false, but I don't see how that would impact this.

Comment: I'm also having this problem. My client populates the List that should be empty with an object that has just been constructed with default constructor. Did you find the answer?

Comment: My workaround for now has been to validate objects I get passed in. In the case of all null fields, I remove them from the set.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but maybe setting the

```
@XmlElemet(nillable=true)
public List<myObject> list;
```

is what you looking for?